# Openstreetmap: filter out data that have been edited after some timestamp

Tags: perl, csv, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I want to get OSM data after some timestamp - in other words the last records after a certain timestamp. I have downloaded the osm file of the area. I went through the osmosis  documentation but could not find a way to filter it by time. The result should be same as when we use the timestamp-argument.  Well how to do that:

- I could use the overpass but the area is large and overpass timed out many times
- I could use the osmconvert-tool (cf the manual: m.m.i24.cc/osmconvert.c )

Some of the following statements might be useful for the task:

```
 "--timestamp=<date_time> add a timestamp to the data\n"
 "--timestamp=NOW-<seconds> add a timestamp in seconds before now\n"
```

What I have tried is the following;

```
./osmfilter austria-latest.osm --keep="$key=$school" |
./osmconvert - --all-to-nodes --csv="@id @lat @lon @timestamp $key name" --csv-headline |
```

but this fails. How to  get the data out of the osm-pbf-file. Should I use the statements drop! or should i name a certain time from timestamp to timestamp!?

Comment: "but this fails." How? Unless you tell us you're wasting peoples time.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 0.7.50 [Overpass API](http://overpass-api.de) provides a way to query for data, which changed since a given timestamp or in a given timeframe. It is even possible to restrict the change analysis to certain tags (or filter criteria). Please check the Overpass API Wiki page for more details on "[diff](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Delta_between_two_dates_.28.22diff.22.29)" and "[adiff](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Augmented_Delta_between_two_dates_.28.22adiff.22.29)" keywords.

Working with Overpass API ina way is much more convenient than trying to process a full planet history, which takes at least 35GB to download and requires more complex post-processing.

Answer (score 0):

You want to process OSM history planet (extracts): https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm/full